# Perl POE DirWatcher

Tags: perl, poe

Can someone tell me if POE::Component::DirWatch works with an ftp directory .show me how you would watch a directory over ftp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No it won't.
2. FTP servers don't have any sort of notification method, so the only way you could do this would be to periodically run a `LIST` command on the remote directory and note any changes. Extra helpfully, there is *no true standard for the format of the listing returned by `LIST`*. Anyway, if you wanted to go this route, you could start with [PoCo-Client-SimpleFTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/POE%3a%3aComponent%3a%3aClient%3a%3aSimpleFTP) and write a new component that emits events when files change on the remote server. Strong knowledge of FTP is recommended.